# State validation in a JavaScript registration form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, if-statement

I could do this:

```
var statevalidation = document.registration.statetextbox;
var state = statevalidation.value;

if(state=="AL" || state=="al" state=="AK" || state=="ak" || ...)
{
    document.getElementById("statemsg").innerHTML=("Good to go.");
    statemsg.style.color="green";
}
else
{
    statemsg.innerHTML=("Invalid state.");
    statemsg.style.color="red";
}
```

However, that leaves me with a long and unsavory if statement. I was wondering if someone knows a "cleaner" way of making sure that users put in a correct state abbreviation?

Comment: Why don't you just use a [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)?

Comment: @BilltheLizard because I am using Ziptastic API to automatically populate state and city textboxes in my form based on the zip code. If Ziptastic doesn't fetch those values for some reason, I want to make sure that users can manually put everything in (rare scenario).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly "cleaner", but how about something like...

```
var state = statevalidation.value.toUpperCase();
var states = ["AL", "AK", ...];
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
  if (states[i] == state) {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (found) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Adding toUpperCase() removes the need for worrying about lowercase input, as it automatically translates it to uppercase. I will just use that and type in only uppercase abbreviations into my if statement since I don't understand loops too well yet. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: OK, you're welcome.  If it's not obvious `toLowerCase()` is the opposite function also available to you

Comment: I would also add, @user, that if you don't fully understand loops then I would seriously recommend that you spend to some time to learn about them.  They are one of the fundamental building blocks of most languages